# How can I implement sprite layering in a 2.5D game?

Tags: 2d

I started making a game, which has a 3D engine under it, but achieves a 2D look by using ab orthographic camera and billboards. Similar to how Don't starve, Realm of the Mad God and (I think) the new Stardew Valley manages entity rendering.

All three games I posted have structures in them (grass, trees, etc), and the player can go behind them. I want to achieve this effect. Of course, by having a fixed Z coordinate for the entities (I use Z sorting) isn't enough for this.

I once achieved this effect by making the entity's Z coordinate change based on their clip space position, but this I felt like this wasn't the best solution.

Basically, what's the best (fastest) way to achieve the above mentioned effect?

Comment: How is having a z coodinate for the entities not enough? I´m not sure I understand your problem...

Comment: What's fastest is going to depend on what tech you have available. Focus on (1) does it work, and (2) does it run fast enough for the game's needs. Realm of the Mad God uses z sorting (based on z _after_ rotation of course). It works for their needs, and is fast enough.

Comment: be more precise on what is the engine underlying your game.Unity 3d, for instance, handle this stuff with sorting order on sprites.

Answer (score 1):

You can try rendering objects in order of their Y position of the bottom of the sprite/object. Closer to the bottom of the screen = closer to the viewer and therefore obscures anything higher up than it. This isn't very flexible but it is simple.